# JS: Selecting a DIV based on its onClick value

Tags: javascript, html

I have several different `div`s with same `class`, no `id` and only their `onClick` function separating them so they are uniquely identifiable, like this:

```
<div class="nest" onclick="nested.selection('VALUE1'); return false;">
  ... something inside the div ...
</div>
<div class="nest" onclick="nested.selection('VALUE2'); return false;">
  ... something inside the div ...
</div>
```

I would need to find and delete an entire `div` based on the specified `onClick` value, but since I cannot use getElementById, Class or Name, how is this lookup achievable with JS (not jQuery)?

Comment: you can use/pass "this" in the JS function which will point to the div element invoke the click function

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the onClick responder ?

Comment: Select by html tag https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: @raphaelSeguin - No, I'm not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
document.querySelector('[onclick="nested.selection(\'VALUE2\'); return false;"]').remove()
```

Comment: Can you motivate why this answer is better than the other ones?

Comment: I think it neatly does the job in one line without having to iterate through all elements when searching for the one needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = document.querySelectorAll('.nest');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const item = event.target;
        item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
    });
}
```

This code will remove div after clicking on it.
Im attaching event handler to all 'nest' elements and then after clicking on specific item removing it.

Comment: Its always more elegant to not use inline onclick function, better to use addEventlisteners to not mix html code with js code.

Comment: There is no onClick action expected from the user for the element to be removed, the element should be removed (as in not displayed at all) when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
   var nested = {
        selection: function (a, e) {
            var element = e.currentTarget;
           element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }

    }
```

html

```
<div class="nest" onclick="nested.selection('VALUE1',event); return false;">
    ... something inside the div ...VALUE1
</div>
<div class="nest" onclick="nested.selection('VALUE2',event); return false;">
    ... something inside the div ...VALUE2
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot edit the html part at all, JS would need to look it up as it is.

Comment: Ok don't need pass event;  var nested = {
            selection: function (a) {
                var element = event.currentTarget;
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
            }

        }

Comment: He doesn't want to remove the element when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to click anything here. Just pass the argument. Like so:

```
deleteWithArg('VALUE1');
```

```js
function deleteWithArg(deleteElement) {
 var nst = document.getElementsByClassName("nest");
 for(var i = 0; i < nst.length; i++)
 {
    let atr = nst.item(i).getAttribute('onclick').match(/'([^']+)'/)[1];
    if (atr == deleteElement) {
   nst.item(i).parentNode.removeChild(nst.item(i));
    }
 } 
}
deleteWithArg('VALUE1');
```

```html
<div class="nest" onclick="nested.selection('VALUE1'); return false;">
  ... something inside the div with value VALUE1...
</div>
<div class="nest" onclick="nested.selection('VALUE2'); return false;">
  ... something inside the div with value VALUE2...
</div>
```